# What can we say about groups $G$ with $H_3(G)=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group. What can we say about groups such that $H_3(G)=0$? If a characterization is not possible, then knowing examples of such groups would be good? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are the coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I do not understand the question: Do you want to see examples of such groups? It is quite clear that there is no alternative characterization of this class.

Comment: @ studiosus, yes non-trivial examples. @sanath yes coeff. are in \mathbb{Z}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, $H_3(\mathbb{Z})=0$, since for $G=\mathbb{Z}$ the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ consists of Laurent polynomials $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$, and a free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is given by
$$
0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}] \xrightarrow{1-t} \mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}] \xrightarrow{t\mapsto 1} \mathbb{Z}.
$$
Since it has only length $2$, it follows that $H_n(\mathbb{Z})=H^n(\mathbb{Z})=0$ for all $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Thanks but are there other examples other than free groups where this happens. I would be interested in groups such that $H_2(G)\neq 0$ but $H_3(G)=0$.

Comment: Take any group of integral homological dimension $2$, e.g., $G=\langle a,b,c,t\mid b^{-1}ab=a^2, c^{-1}ac=a^3,bc=cb,tbc^{-1}=bc^{-1}t, ta=at\rangle$. For details see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.1084).